# 4.6 QWebView memory leaks?

Tags: qt, memory, memory-leaks, qwebview

I wrote a quick test app to use the google analytics scripts in a client app. It works fine using `QWebView` and

```
QWebFrame* pFrame = m_pWebView->page()->mainFrame();
pFrame->setContent(arrayHtml);
pFrame->evaluateJavaScript(strScript);
```

But no matter what I do I cannot get it to release memory. Every time I call the script it keeps adding to memory used in the process. I even try `delete m_pWebView` and the memory usage is still there. I also tried the `QWebSettings::clearMemoryCaches()` call and it did not work.

Is this a memory leak or is there some other magic I can use to get it to not consume all the PC's memory.

Comment: Does it happen with newer version of Qt? 4.6 is quite old.

Comment: This is still here, be sure :)